# Express.js - TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined

Tags: node.js, api, express

On my Express.js backend, when a user wants to reset their password, a link is sent to their email via Sendgrid and when the link is clicked the user receives this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined
    at resetPasswordController.showResetPassword (/root/apps/AskArya-Node.js-Vue.js/Server/app/http/controllers/auth/resetPasswordController.js:11:33)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/apps/AskArya-Node.js-Vue.js/Server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/root/apps/AskArya-Node.js-
```

The code for the resetPasswordController is:

```
  class resetPasswordController extends controller {
  showResetPassword(req, res) {
    const title = 'بازیابی رمز عبور';
    res.render('home/auth/passwords/reset', {
      recaptcha: this.recaptcha.render(),
      title,
      token: req.params.token
    });
  }

  async resetPasswordProccess(req, res, next) {
    await this.recaptchaValidation(req, res);
    let result = await this.validationData(req);
    if (result) {
      return this.resetPassword(req, res);
    }

    this.back(req, res);
  }

  async resetPassword(req, res) {
    let field = await PasswordReset.findOne({
      $and: [{ email: req.body.email }, { token: req.body.token }]
    });
    if (!field) {
      req.flash('errors', 'اطلاعات وارد شده صحیح نیست لطفا دقت کنید');
      return this.back(req, res);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this error comes from this line:

```
recaptcha: this.recaptcha.render(),
```

This is because this.recaptcha is null.
Probably, this code was copied from somewhere else, where this.recaptcha was defined.

Comment: I commented it out before because I didn't want to use it anymore, let me try it with Recaptcha.